# PHP mail function not seding without additiional flag

Tags: php, email

I am moving a site to another server and am having an issue with PHP mail.

```
$headers .= "From: Name  <support@test.com>" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: support@test.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: support@test.com\r\n";


mail($send_to, 'Web contact' ,$message,$headers,"-r support@test.com");
```

The only way I can get mail to send is by adding the -r flag it doesn't seem to matter what e-mail address is entered after the flag.

This is a migration from Centos 5 to 6 and I believe mail is now using Postfix as opposed to sendMail.

Is there a Postfix setting that I can change to stop having to add this flag to every call of the mail function?

Additionally is there a way to force the use of sendMail instead of using Postfix if I can't fix this?

Comment: You need to add `null` in there too. As per the manual but using the `-f` flag `mail('nobody@example.com', 'the subject', 'the message', null,
   '-fwebmaster@example.com');` - try that. `mail($send_to, 'Web contact' ,$message,$headers, null, "-r support@test.com");`

Comment: I actually had the same issue myself this morning lol - quite a coincidence I'd say.

Comment: That is a bit better not having to add headers but I don't want to have to add the -r flag either.

Comment: so, did you try the `-f` flag instead?

Comment: I don't want to add any flag, there was no need for a flag on current server.